# SSRS Matrix to Excel Export creates additional Row

Tags: reporting-services

I have Matrix table with "Indicator" in column Group and "NAME, ID and DATE" in Row Group.
DATE is toggled by NAME. it works fine when we view on browser. The problem comes when we export in Excel- it leaves an additional row. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjrFB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxb3i.jpg)  -- here you go with the latest Screenshot

Comment: A pic of the Design View might help. It sounds like you don't have a header row for the date group so Excel has to create one - row 93 isn't expanded but needs to show the indicators somewhere.

Comment: Hi - Please see attached image . I had changed the name earlier due to sensitivity. but this is the original report

Comment: Your design view doesn't seem to match the output. Also, can you select a cell so that the table frame shows up with the grouping braces and lines on the left? Either way, I still think the issue is due to having other data displayed on the same line as the hidden date. Maybe add a row for the group and hide that instead?

Comment: If the indicators are for each day, there shouldn't be any showing when the dates are hidden - maybe just a total of Ys. Your current line should be the TOTAL line while a new line would be the grouped line.

Comment: in the out put sent earlier i was trying to show the picture which probably wasnt clear enough . the one sent later is the true copy. but the output would be same except for fields. the indicator is same as column label -bear in mind this is not tablix . its a matric model.